# How active is my mobile phone when I'm not using it?

Tags: data-synchronization, data-transfer, cellular-data

I wonder whether there is any study/website/research work or a place to check how much data my phone is sending when I'm not using it. My question is: when my phone is off, but I'm not actively using it (just left it on my desk) do any of the apps on my phone send any network data to servers, etc.? Can I somehow check this information on my phone (I have iPhone 7) or maybe someone already did such an analysis?

Comment: The iPhone fetches notifications and similar things from apples servers. This communication is, of course, protected with a transport protocol like tls so you cannot see directly what's in. In addition the phone may holds connections for things like Wifi Calling etc.

Comment: @Felix.v.O. Is it possible to at least get an estimation how much bandwidth is used for those notifications?

Comment: Yes, you can see this if you use mobile data at the following position: Settings > Cellular > System Services

Answer (score 3):

Since iOS 10, I’ve seen very good ability to control activity. Even better, you can see exactly what runs, hour per hour what’s front most and what background apps are taking energy.

[image: iOS 13 battery settings screen showing app usage for the day]

If you want no background - just turn that off for all apps. Then review the activity graphs for a couple days. If you want more activity, enable background and remove apps that are more active than you care or selectively disable background activity so you know apps only run when you ask them to run.

[image: iOS 13 battery settings screen showing app usage for the week]

If you’re technically minded, the Charles proxy is excellent to log outbound traffic without needing to manage your router. I also use Ubiquiti network routers so know and log access / block some traffic, but that’s on the network side, not the iOS side.

I don’t think getting outside analyses are as important as choosing your apps so you know how they are funding development. If the app is slick and free, you’re paying them in data / marketing / eyeballs in many cases.

Comment: Friendly tip: adding an "`l`" at the end of the uploaded image filename and before the extension will reduce it to the "large" size, instead of the gigantic original size they are now. For example, editing your first image URL from `UdFnM.jpg` to `UdFnMl.jpg` allows it to display much nicer on desktop.

Comment: Hmm - they look great on the iPhone and iPad where I upload and view. I wonder if that’s something we should report as a bug on [meta] - thank you so much for mentioning that they look gigantic, @maxathousand This has been [a pet peeve of mine since 2012.](https://apple.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/1272/resize-images-programmatically) and it was a lot of hassle earlier. I wonder why desktop doesn’t just add that sizing? It impacts quality a lot on iOS devices so I’m not convinced but I’ll try it out.

Comment: It may display differently on devices with different pixel densities. I was viewing fullscreen on a desktop with a lower pixel density than the newer Apple devices, so that might be why it appeared extra large for me.

Answer (score 1):

> I wonder whether there is any study/website/research work or a place to check how much data my phone is sending when I'm not using it.

Yes.  I found this research article (behind a paywall) that discusses these points from a battery and energy optimization point of view:  [Smartphone Background Activities in the Wild: Origin, Energy Drain, and Optimization](https://dl.acm.org/doi/abs/10.1145/2789168.2790107)

From the Abstract

---

- First, we present a large-scale measurement study that performs an in-depth analysis of the activities of various apps running in background on thousands of phones in the wild.
- Second, we quantify the amount of battery drain by all such background activities and possible energy saving.
- Third, we develop a metric to measure the usefulness of background activities that is personalized to each user.
- Finally, we present a system called HUSH (screen-off optimizer) that monitors the metric online and automatically identifies and suppresses background activities during screen-off periods that are not useful to the user experience.

https://dl.acm.org/doi/abs/10.1145/2789168.2790107